# Save data from Custom field in Shipping Method in Onepage Checkout

Tags: php, magento, checkout

**Hello**,

**My problem**: I want to add a checkbox next to a shipping method and on checkout success, retrieve the value of the checkbox (checked/unchecked) and if it's checked, add a new record in a custom SQL table, where one of the value is the id of the order just created.

I added the checkbox in `template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml` (that was the easy part). And the custom SQL table is already created.
But now, how can I get the result of the checkbox and the orderid ?

In `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`, there is the save informations actions, can this be helpful ? I was thinking maybe if I overwrite the `saveOrderAction` I can achieve what I want, but I have no idea how.

Thanks for your time, I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: If it's not relying on the shipping method selected, could you just add it as an order attribute?   Then all the saving would be taken care of and you'd only have to call the order attribute when the checkout success page loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know why I over complicated this, but I just had to add an attribute to the order!